# Connecting Oracle with VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 and Oracle 11g in my Window 7.

Oracle seem to be fine because i can connect to System user, Create user and create database.
But the problem is that I can not connect the Oracle to my VB.net project and there is no System.Data.OracleClient Namespace. Do I need to install Oracle Client in my computer even though i have installed Oracle Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [Oracle Data Provider for .net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), which is a separate download. Older oracle versions relied upon OleDb, but newer versions provide their own Data Provider.

Answer (score 1):

Check this sites:

[Getting Started with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (VB.NET Version)](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedVBVersion/GettingStartedNET_VBVersion.htm)

[Using Oracle VB.NET](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/oracle.aspx)